# How to retrieve min and max cosine?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm computing the cosine similarity between two textual fields and I need to retrieve the resulting min and max cosine value.

By doing this:

```py
for t in trigrams:
            emb = model_ft.get_sentence_vector(''.join(t))
            print(t, emb[:3])

            a = emb

            b = embeddings_subj

            def cos_sim(a, b):
                dot_product = np.dot(a, b)
                norm_a = np.linalg.norm(a)
                norm_b = np.linalg.norm(b)
                return dot_product / (norm_a * norm_b)

            cosine_trig = [(cos_sim(a,b))]

            print('Cosine trigrams:',cosine_trig)
```

as output I'm having the resulting cosine similarity per each trigram. For example:

```
('lastra', 'di', 'tomba') [-0.04048021  0.01067416 -0.00855918]
Cosine trigrams: [0.33791965]
('di', 'tomba', 'intonacata') [ 0.00265847  0.01100874 -0.05969027]
Cosine trigrams: [0.4009857]
('tomba', 'intonacata', 'e') [-0.02288066  0.0349679  -0.0527756 ]
Cosine trigrams: [0.34407777]
('intonacata', 'e', 'dipinta') [0.02718818 0.06673413 0.01361684]
Cosine trigrams: [0.41566172]
```

How to find the min and max cosine similarity according to the results I got?

My desired output would be:

```
('lastra', 'di', 'tomba') [-0.04048021  0.01067416 -0.00855918]
Cosine trigrams: [0.33791965]
('di', 'tomba', 'intonacata') [ 0.00265847  0.01100874 -0.05969027]
Cosine trigrams: [0.4009857]
('tomba', 'intonacata', 'e') [-0.02288066  0.0349679  -0.0527756 ]
Cosine trigrams: [0.34407777]
('intonacata', 'e', 'dipinta') [0.02718818 0.06673413 0.01361684]
Cosine trigrams: [0.41566172]

Min cosine: 0.34407777
Max cosine: 0.41566172
```

I was thinking to create a Numpy array by using the outputs then search for the min and max value directly into the array but I'm not sure.

thanks

Comment: Did you try doing what you wrote in your last paragraph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't define that function inside your `for` loop. You should define it outside the `for` loop. Otherwise you are constantly redeclaring it!

Then to handle the max/min thing, just use variables `max_cosine_trig` and `min_trigram_trig` to hold them.

```
def cos_sim(a, b):
    dot_product = np.dot(a, b)
    norm_a = np.linalg.norm(a)
    norm_b = np.linalg.norm(b)
    return dot_product / (norm_a * norm_b)

max_cosine_trig = None
min_cosine_trig = None

for t in trigrams:
    emb = model_ft.get_sentence_vector("".join(t))
    print(t, emb[:3])

    a = emb
    b = embeddings_subj

    cosine_trig = [(cos_sim(a, b))]
    print("Cosine trigrams:", cosine_trig)

    if max_cosine_trig is None or max_cosine_trig < cosine_trig:
        max_cosine_trig = cosine_trig

    if min_cosine_trig is None or min_cosine_trig > cosine_trig:
        min_cosine_trig = cosine_trig


print(f"Max cosine trigrams: {max_cosine_trig}")
print(f"Min cosine trigrams: {min_cosine_trig}")
```